# Show that $K[x]/(x)$ is isomorphic to $K$, where the map is defined by sending a polynomial to a constant coefficient

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, polynomial-rings, ring-isomorphism

I have a problem here.

show that $K[x]/(x)$ is isomorphic to $K$, where the map is defined by sending a polynomial to a constant coefficient.

My attemot on this problem is to defined a function $f: K[x]/(x) \rightarrow K$.  And then show that $f$ is isomorphic.  However, I don't how the elements of the domain looks like. Can somebody help me?  I will turly appreciate it.

Comment: $K[x]$ is the ring of polynomials in $x$ with coefficients in $K$.

Comment: Any element of $K[x] /(x) $ is an equivalence class consisting of polynomials which give same remainder when divided by $x$. Thus each class can be represented by just the constant term of the polynomial and that gives you the isomorphism with $K$.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE! You're most of the way there.

Elements of $K[x]$ are polynomials with coefficients in $K$. Knowing this, you already have a function

$$a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \ldots + a_n x^n \longmapsto a_0 : K[x] \to K$$

which takes a polynomial as input and outputs the constant term of that polynomial. For instance, we have things like $f(x^2 + 1) = 1$ and $f(9x^4 - 2x^2 + 11x - 3) = -3$ and so on.

Do you see why this map is surjective? Do you see what its kernel is? With these facts together, can you use the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_A_(rings)) to get the isomorphism you want?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you.  I see the map is surjective but I am sorry I don't know what is the kernel there?

Comment: @Matt: the kernel is a set which maps to $0$ under the homomorphism and hence here it consists of polynomials with constant term $0$.

Comment: Wow thanks Paramanand